# using array_search for multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

using array_search in a 1 dimensional array is simple

```
$array = array("apple", "banana", "cherry");
$searchValue = "cherry";
$key = array_search($searchValue, $array);

echo $key;
```

but how about an multi dimensional array?

```
    #RaceRecord

    [CarID] [ColorID] [Position]
[0]    1        1         3
[1]    2        1         1
[2]    3        2         4
[3]    4        2         2
[4]    5        3         5
```

for example i want to get the index of the car whose position is 1. How do i do this?

Comment: An "associative array" and a "multidimensional array" are two different things. Your example is a multidimensional array that happens to have one axis being associative.

Comment: oh i see sorry, im gonna edit the title

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
function find_car_with_position($cars, $position) {
    foreach($cars as $index => $car) {
        if($car['Position'] == $position) return $index;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: excuse me, could i have some clarifications? the $position value is the value of Position while the $cars is the array itself? thank you for the reply

Comment: SikretMiseon - yes. @diEcho - what "more easy" solution can you think of that wouldn't be very implementation-specific?

Answer (score 67):

In php 5.5.5 & later versions,
you can try this

```
$array_subjected_to_search =array(
array(
        'name' => 'flash',
        'type' => 'hero'
    ),

array(
        'name' => 'zoom',
        'type' => 'villian'
    ),

array(
        'name' => 'snart',
        'type' => 'antihero'
    )
);
$key = array_search('snart', array_column($array_subjected_to_search, 'name'));
var_dump($array_subjected_to_search[$key]);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "snart" ["type"]=> string(8) "antihero" }
```

working sample : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/19385da11fe0614ef5f84f58b6dae80bd216fc01

Documentation about array_column can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: what if I need to search where name = `snart` and type = `antihero`

Comment: @Smith :Use Loupax's answer & combine your matches in the return statement with &&

Comment: So this was not working if we have an associative array?

Comment: No it doesn't , check loupax's answer for that

Answer (score 24):

You can try this

```
array_search(1, array_column($cars, 'position'));
```

Answer (score 14):

Hooray for one-liners!

```
$index = array_keys(array_filter($array, function($item){ return $item['property'] === 'whatever';}))[0];
```

Let's make it more clear:

```
array_filter(
    $array, 
    function ($item) {
        return $item['property'] === 'whatever';
    }
);
```

returns an array that contains all the elements that fulfill the condition in the callback, while maintaining their original array keys. We basically need the key of the first element of that array.

To do this we wrap the result in an `array_keys()` call and get it's first element. 
This specific example makes the assumption that at least one matching element exists, so you might need an extra check just to be safe.

Comment: This was especially handy because I was looking for all the indices that contain a value, so all I had to do was drop the `[0]` at the end. The `array_search('needle', array_column($haystack, 'column_key'));` method only returns the first.

Answer (score 6):

I basically 'recreated' underscore.js's findWhere method which is to die for.

The function:

```
function findWhere($array, $matching) {
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $is_match = true;
        foreach ($matching as $key => $value) {

            if (is_object($item)) {
                if (! isset($item->$key)) {
                    $is_match = false;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (! isset($item[$key])) {
                    $is_match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (is_object($item)) {
                if ($item->$key != $value) {
                    $is_match = false;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if ($item[$key] != $value) {
                    $is_match = false;
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }

        if ($is_match) {
            return $item;   
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Example:

```
$cars = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Toyota'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Ford')
);

$car = findWhere($cars, array('id' => 1));
```

or

```
$car = findWhere($cars, array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Toyota'
));
```

I'm sure this method could easily reduce LOC.  I'm a bit tired. :P

Answer (score 2):

actually all array functions are designed for single dimension array.You always need to keep in mind that you are applying it on single dimension array.

```
function find_car_with_position($cars, $position) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($cars);$i++){
        if(array_search($search_val, $cars[$i]) === false){
             // if value not found in array.....
        }  
        else{
            // if value is found in array....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `count` in [for loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)