# Most efficient way to search a multidimensional array and return a needle and its position in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, search

Take this simple multidimensional array:

```
$images Array (

  [0] => Array (
    [image_id] => 18
    [votes] => 12
  )

  [1] => Array (
    [image_id] => 76
    [votes] => 10
  )

  ...

  [n] => Array (
    [image_id] => 2
    [votes] => 1
  )
)
```

What is the best way to search for a certain `image_id` value in the overall array, and then return that `image_id`'s position within the larger array, and return the corresponding `votes` at the same time? Would some variation of `array_search()` be able to manage this?

Currently, I'm using a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $i = 0;
  if ($image['image_id'] == $someNeedle) {
    $resultSet['image'] = $image;
    $resultSet['position'] = $i;

    return $resultSet;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

This however seems overly complex. Is there a native PHP function that could speed this up/make my code more semantic? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694843/using-array-search-for-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you'll find another method that is faster, or more clear to read.

```
foreach ($images as $position => $image) {
  if ($image['image_id'] === $someNeedle) {
    return compact('image', 'position');
  }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Comment: why three = , please explain the use of === ?

Comment: Interesting. I've never heard of `compact()` before. +1 for that.

Comment: @FaceOfJock I default to using strict comparisons in php simply because it produces what I feel is a more expected behavior. My answer doesn't really change much if you use `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way to return exactly what you want. You could simplify it slightly, but not much:

```
foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
    if ($image['image_id'] == $someNeedle) {
        return array(
            'image' => $image,
            'position' => $key,
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `key` of your array instead of `i`,it will give you the position,it can be a little more fast:

```
foreach ($images as $key=>$image) {
  if ($image['image_id'] == $someNeedle) {
    $resultSet['image'] = $image;
    $resultSet['position'] = $key;

    return $resultSet;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_search($needle, array_column($array, 'column'));
```

with credits to HCDINH's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39157504/4474165).