# Extract [cat_ID] from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the following array (just a part of the complete array) and I want to extract the value of [cat_ID].

```
Array ([1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 21 [name] => z_aflyst [slug] => z_aflyst
[term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 23 [taxonomy] => category 
[description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [object_id] => 7 [cat_ID] => 21 
[cat_name] => z_aflyst ))
```

So I need to extract the 21 in this case. However, I only want to extract the `cat_ID` if the `cat_name` equals `z_aflyst`.

Comment: Sure you could use this as a starter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694843/using-array-search-for-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give that you have an array of objects:

```
Array (
[1] => stdClass Object 
( 
[term_id] => 21 
[name] => z_aflyst 
[slug] => z_aflyst
[term_group] => 0 
[term_taxonomy_id] => 23 
[taxonomy] => category 
[description] => 
[parent] => 0 
[count] => 1 
[object_id] => 7 
[cat_ID] => 21 
[cat_name] => z_aflyst )
)

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    if($item->cat_name == 'z_aflyst')
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: where did $items come from?

Comment: You have var_dump-ed an array containing stdClass objects (currently 1 object) as I can see it..no code was provided...

Comment: $items is that array you posted in your initial post.

Comment: he assumed $items=array(..your array..);

Comment: you dont need to foreach.. this will go through all elements without the need for that

Comment: @ElzoValugi You missed the part in the question where OP states "just a part of the complete array"

Comment: @ Elzo Valugi: Why? He has an array of objects.

Comment: I think he meant that his array has more keys than the one that is showing.

Comment: My array has a lot of keys. The "power" of Wordpress ;) But this solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your array is in this example a little more than a simple array, is a [standard object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php). And you can take advantage of this. You can the properties of a standard object by this formula:

```
$object->property;
```

in your case the object is

```
$object = $array[1];
```

or by this formula as an array

```
$array[key];
```

in your case to get the value of cat_ID:

```
$object->cat_ID;
```

So your code will be something like:

```
if ($object->cat_name == 'z_aflyst') {
     // do stuff with your cat_ID value
     echo $object->cat_ID;
}
// will echo 21 only of the cat_name has value 'z_aflyst'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of [standard objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), which properties can be accessed using the arrow (object) operator `->`.

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter out unwanted elements of the array:

```
// Assuming your array is called $items
$filtered = array_filter($items, function($v) {
    return $v->cat_name === 'z_aflyst';
});
```

After that, you can "flatten" the array using [`array_map()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) so that it only contains the cat_ID if you wish:

```
$filtered = array_map(function($v) {
    return $v->cat_ID;
}, $filtered);
```

This will leave you with a one-dimension, indexed array of cat_IDs.