# Find argument in array if other argument exists

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My task is to find value of argument if other argument exists in other array. I don't know how to describe it correctly by words so here is pseudocode:

```
if $_POST['from'] == X
```

Find in `$array` key `'name' == X` and its key `'timezone'` and save this value as argument:

```
    $array = [
        [
            'name'     => 'A',
            'timezone' => 'AB',
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'B',
            'timezone' => 'BC',
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'C',
            'timezone' => 'AB',
        ],
```

If `$_POST['name'] == B`, `'timezone' == BC`

I could make it by 10x if X, timezone = B but I think it's not best way. I'm now in this step:

```
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
         foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            if ($value2 == $_POST['from']) {
                if ($key2 == 'timezone') {
                    echo $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using array\_search for multi dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694843/using-array-search-for-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as the `name` values are unique:

```
echo array_column($array, 'timezone', 'name')[$_POST['from']];
```

- Extract an array with `name` as key and `timezone` as value
- Access the array with key `$_POST['from']`

Of course you might check to see if it exists first (assuming that you have previously checked `isset($_POST['from'])`):

```
$tz = array_column($array, 'timezone', 'name');

if(isset($tz[$_POST['from']])) {
    echo $tz[$_POST['from']];
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting use of array_column - hadn't ever seen it like this before.

Comment: Much thanks. I tried with array_column but didn't know about such developped possibilites in this function.