# PHP recursive array_search

Tags: php

From the code below I can compare the 2 arrays and find out the `$subset` elements position range in `$array`.

```
$array = [8,2,3,7,4,6,5,1,9];
$subset = [6,3,7];

function get_range($array, $subset)
{
    $min = sizeof($array);
    $max = 0;
    
    foreach($subset as $value) {
        $occurrence = array_search($value, $array);
        if( $occurrence < $min ) {
            $min = $occurrence;
        }
        if( $occurrence >  $max ) {
            $max = $occurrence;
        }
    }
    
    return [$min, $max];
}
$range = get_range($array, $subset);  // result as an array -> [2, 5]
```

However, I want to do a recursive `array_search` for my multidimentional array like:

```
$subset =  array (
  array(6,3,7),
  array(4,2,9),
  array(3,5,6),
);
```

How can I do this? Expecting results -> `[2, 5], [1, 8], [2, 6]`.

Comment: Why do you need a recursion?

Comment: Does this help you answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694843/using-array-search-for-multi-dimensional-array/31590256

Comment: @ Zhorov my $subset array to compare with is dynamic and generated from scripts, I'm thinking to save the array_search results into an array but don't know how. @PatricNox I've seen the thread but no help, I need the smaller array $subset elements position range as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a recursion here, simply add an additional `loop` in the `get_range()` function. The following example is based on your code and is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?php
$array = [8,2,3,7,4,6,5,1,9];
$subsets =  array (
  array(6,3,7),
  array(4,2,9),
  array(3,5,6),
);

function get_range($array, $subsets)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($subsets as $subset) {
        $min = sizeof($array);
        $max = 0;
        foreach($subset as $value) {
            $occurrence = array_search($value, $array);
            if( $occurrence < $min ) {
                $min = $occurrence;
            }
            if( $occurrence >  $max ) {
                $max = $occurrence;
            }
        }
        $result[] = [$min, $max];
    }
    
    return $result;
}

$range = get_range($array, $subsets);
echo print_r($range, true);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 8 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! and is exactly what I want.